# Help with overriding python import

Tags: python

In application no.1 I have a settings.py file, and a utils.py, which contains the following:

```
from application_one import settings

def someFunction():
    // do some logic here based on imported settings
```

Then in application no.2 I do:

```
from application_one.utils import someFunction
```

In application no.2 I have a local settings.py and when I import 'someFunction()' I want to use the local settings.py not the file from application no.1. So how would one overide the import in application no.2?

Comment: If you want it to be doing something else, then `someFunction` should be defined outside `application_one`. If it's in `application_one`, it should be specific to application number one. (Probably some or all of `application_one.utils` should be moved out of the `application_one` package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def someFunction(settings=settings):
    …  # Unmodified code ('settings' refers to the local 'settings' variable)
```

(this lets `someFunction()` use the Application 1 settings by default) and then call it from Application 2 by sending the local settings:

```
someFunction(application2_settings)  # Explicit settings sent by Application 2
```

One advantage of this approach is that your code in both Application 1 and 2 explicitly shows that `someFunction()` gives results that are setting-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure that you import your settings after you have loaded the function you wish to overload.

However it seems that you'd be better of loading with namespaces intact, as this would prevent this entire issue from occurring.